# React Native expo load an image when device is offline

Tags: react-native, expo, offline-caching

I am trying to load an image when the device is offline. Basically it's an offline notice like bellow image, so the image will only show when the device is offline. I have already referred to expo offline docs https://docs.expo.io/guides/offline-support/  but it's not working I think I am missing something please help me. Show me an example of how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) the image will be available locally in standalone apps if you use `assetBundlePatterns`, which is enabled by default. see: https://docs.expo.io/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets/#bundling-assets

2) in expo client, if you want it to be available when offline you can cache the image. see: https://docs.expo.io/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets/#pre-loading-and-caching-assets